# Rspec controller spec claims function ios not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing out one of my controllers and have attempted to stub a function call with no luck.  Here is the function:

```
def fetch_typeform_response
    hp = HealthProfile.find(params[:id])
    form = TypeformService.new('x')
    response = form.getResponse("query=#{ hp[:id] }")

    if response['total_items'] != 1
        if response[:response_id].present?
            response = form.getResponse("included_response_ids=#{ hp[:response_id] }")
        end
    end

    if response['total_items'] == 1

        response = response['items'].first
        health_profile = HealthProfile.map_typeform_response(response)

        if health_profile.save
            health_profile.reload
            redirect_to health_profile_path(health_profile), notice: "Successfully updated the health profile response."
            return
        end

    end

    redirect_to health_profiles_path, notice: "We could not locate the health profile."
end
```

In my test, I stub out `:getResponse` and `:map_typeform_response` since they involve an outside API:

```
it "expects to fetch typeform response" do
  new_hp = build(:health_profile)
  new_hp_after_mapping = build(:health_profile)

  allow_any_instance_of(TypeformService).to receive(:getResponse).and_return({ 'total_items': 1, 'items': [ new_hp ] }.as_json)
  allow_any_instance_of(HealthProfile).to receive(:map_typeform_response).and_return(new_hp_after_mapping)

  get :fetch_typeform_response, params: { id: @hp.id }
  expect(response).to redirect_to(health_profile_path(@hp.id))
end
```

But I receive the error: `HealthProfile does not implement #map_typeform_response`.

If I remove the stub line, I see the error:

```
Failure/Error: p "Using health_profile_id: #{response['hidden']['id']}"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Which is occurring inside the `:map_typeform_response` function (so clearly it is called!).  Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `map_typeform_response` method on class `HealthProfile` and not on instance of the class.

change

```
allow_any_instance_of(HealthProfile).to receive(:map_typeform_response).and_return(new_hp_after_mapping)
```

to

```
allow(HealthProfile).to receive(:map_typeform_response).and_return(new_hp_after_mapping)
```

That happens because rspec prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on a real object. Default is true since Rails 4.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

### Some more recommendations

I'd also recommend to move building of `new_hp` and `new_hp_after_mapping` variables to `let`

```
let(:new_hp) { build(:health_profile) }
let(:new_hp_after_mapping) { build(:health_profile) }
```

move stubs to `before`

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(TypeformService).to receive(:getResponse).and_return({ 'total_items': 1, 'items': [ new_hp ] }.as_json)
  allow(HealthProfile).to receive(:map_typeform_response).and_return(new_hp_after_mapping)
end
```

so your test will look like

```
it "expects to fetch typeform response" do
  # make sure variable @hp intialized in your test.
  get :fetch_typeform_response, params: { id: @hp.id }
  expect(response).to redirect_to(health_profile_path(@hp.id))
end
```